# Managing State without Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

I notice usage of Redux where it's not necessary, for example I have a Post page that loads that post, and it's comments.

They are only rendered on that page, and are not needed elsewhere, I can pass the data to child props from my Post container.

> Now I wonder how do you maintain a clean state when not using Redux? I'm currently loading the post data and the comments data using 2 API calls, and Promise.all() to wait for them both to complete, before hiding the loading.

```
componentDidMount() {
    Promise.all([
        pathService.get(this.props.match.params.slug),
        courseService.get(this.props.match.params.slug)
    ]).then(promises => {
        this.setState({
            loading: false,
            path: promises[0].data,
            courses: promises[1].data
        })
    });
}
```

**Is this the correct way of handling relational data like this? Are there other options, or should I be looking at Redux either way?**

Comment: TBH I've never seen that kind of code inside component. Why not to remove promises and drop the code inside `componentWillReceiveProps` hook?

Comment: How do you generally see people load data from 2 different API endpoints then? In regards to never having seen that kind of code inside a component? What's so odd about it? thanks!

Comment: @kinduser by "remove promises", do you mean to move them up the component tree? The async stuff will have to happen *somewhere*, and componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate are good places for it. Ps, componentWillReceiveProps is in the process of being phased out and should be avoided.

Comment: @NicholasTower What really does that code inside promises here? Is it fetching anything? What are the `pathService` and `courseService` vars?

Comment: `What really does that code inside promises here? Is it fetching anything?` Yes, it is fetching data. As the question says: `I'm currently loading the post data and the comments data using 2 API calls`

Answer (score 4):

I would say that your current method is great if you'd like to continue not using Redux.

Whether or not you use Redux is largely dependent on your familiarity with it and the size of your application. You are correct when you say that it is often used unnecessarily, but it can be a helpful tool sometimes.

For this particular component, Redux might be helpful if you are using the resulting state from the Promises in other components that do not have a direct parent/child relationship with your Post component. You can imagine that passing the resulting state all the way up the component tree and then back down to another component in another arm of the tree might become cumbersome. This is when the Redux store excels, as you can retrieve this state from the store without having to pass it through the entire component tree.

Bonus: If you are looking for other methods and are okay with using brand new React features, look into React hooks. They are a great way to deal with more complex 
state without using Redux at all! https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score -1):

This GitHub URL gives what you are looking for:
https://github.com/fozg/react-light-state 
this library manages state fluently and save to storage very easy, enjoy it!